# Using lpsolve php library

Tags: php, wamp, lpsolve

I need to use **lpsolve** library for one of my projects...
How do i configure it with Apache 2.2 and php 5.3.9 on WAMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lpsolve extension for PHP.

[Here](http://www.peno.be/lp_solve/PHP/5.3/) you can download the PHP extension. Copy the extension to your **php/ext/** folder. Then restart your server and you can use the extensions and the functions.

A tutorial: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/PHP.htm

Comment: is there any other alternative to this that i can use... i want to it as a service to my client application..

Comment: What? Sorry thats a bit confusing.